# How to suspend/resume GCE VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

We need the ability to suspend/resume GCE VMs to optimize the use of Compute Engine resources.

Right now this feature is available in `gcloud alpha`:

```sh
gcloud alpha compute instances suspend INSTANCE_NAMES [INSTANCE_NAMES …] [--async][--discard-local-ssd] [--zone=ZONE] [GCLOUD_WIDE_FLAG …]
```

But when I executed this command I got this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygVZl.png):

> HTTPError 400: Invalid Resource Usage:'Suspend Instance Feature is not available for this project.'

Can anyone suggest to me ways to suspend Google Cloud VM? From the error stated, I get an understanding that we need some permission to include feature in the project. Can anyone suggest to me ways to include Suspend Instance Feature in this project?

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply for early access for this feature and have your project registered with Google. Contact [Google Support](https://cloud.google.com/support/). Include your email address, the project ID in your request and how you will be using the API.

Do not expect a rapid response. My requests sometimes takes several weeks for approval.

Comment: I tried contacting them and its usually the sales team who pick up and they have no clue of early access program and try to sell google cloud services to me. It would be very helpful, if you have idea of specific email id i could write to or specific team i could talk to.

Comment: That is not how access to alpha feature requests work (in my experience). Go to the link that I provided, complete a request and wait. Don't expect approval or a quick reply. I have several requests that are a month old without any update. Some requests are approved in a week. I think it depends on the engineering team and how many people that they want in the program at any given point in time. I would just wait until the beta is available. Alpha features are for testing and providing feedback to Google, not for real-world usage.

Comment: Thanks John. Will make a request in the link provided

Comment: Hey John, In the link you provided, Can you tell me under which heading the request has to be made. The link is ambiguous as selecting console support center lead to my console and after selection of project redirected to same page with no changes.Would you mind elaborating the steps to be followed in the link?

Comment: Just describe what you want to Google Support. In this case specify the gcloud command, the project ID, etc.

Comment: i have pinged the sales team, technical support and the billing support team. They keep redirecting me among the three. can you give me specific email or name a specific team who would be of help in this issue?

Comment: Have you enabled technical support for your account? I cannot provide you email addresses.

Comment: We have basic support option. We have not enabled role based or enterprise support options.

Comment: I hit the same issue and it was odd because I could suspend from the dashboard and with the beta api (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/beta/instances/suspend) but not with `gcloud` script (that was stuck in alpha). Possibly it's a versioning error but I wanted it to work across VM's. My solution was to just use the python sdk with that beta API (using the service account so I don't need to download creds)

Answer (score 1):

This feature is available in beta mode with GCP now.

```
gcloud beta compute instances suspend <instance-name>

gcloud beta compute instances resume <instance-name>
```

I tried this on Gcloud SDK and it has prompted me to install beta utility which worked for me..

More details can be found at
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/compute/instances/suspend

Comment: I love this feature. Although today 30Jan2021, I received this `ERROR: HTTPError 400: E2 VMs currently do not support suspend operation`. This is total BS as this has worked for the last 6 months with no issues.  Very disappointed Google.